# What happened to Darth Tyranus' Lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, revenge-of-the-sith, darth-tyranus

[image]

[image]

When Anakin incapicated Dooku on the Invisible Hand, He(Anakin) cuts off the both hands of the Sith Lord. As a result, Dooku loses his lightsaber to Anakin.

[image] The Sith Lord is dead.

Afterwards,When Anakin comes closer to Palpatine he removed him from the Chair. But,what happened to Tyrnaus' Lightsaber,Afterwards? Did Anakin give it to Palpatine or Did he keep it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It was destroyed when the rear of the Invisible Hand (Dooku's flagship) fell off during the [landing sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwEECZjnPEM&feature=youtu.be&t=41s).

---

- The novelisation indicates that Anakin dropped it near Dooku's body.

  > *Now he stood over a headless corpse that he couldn’t bear to see but
  >   he couldn’t make himself look away, and he knew it hadn’t been a dream
  >   at all, that he’d really done this, the blades were still in his hands
  >   and the ocean of wrong he’d dived into had closed over his head.*
  >   *And he was drowning.*
  >   ***The dead man’s lightsaber tumbled from his loosening fingers. “I-I
  >   couldn’t stop myself…”***
- Which matches what we see in the film, with the discarded saber next to Dooku's [decapitated and debrachiated](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296351/head-is-to-decapitate-as-arm-is-to-what) body.

  [image]
- The lightsaber was left in the conning bridge when the ship began its descent into the Coruscanti atmosphere.

  [image]
  <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_Incredible_Cross-Sections)</sup></sub>
- and **was destroyed shortly afterwards**
  [image]

Comment: But why didn't he just keep it?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - Because it's corrupted. Also, why would he want to? What benefit could he get from taking Dooku's customised lightsaber?

Answer (score 5):

It was destroyed with the *Invisible Hand* moments later.

> Once Skywalker escaped with both Kenobi and Palpatine in tow, Dooku's
>   lightsaber was left behind in Grievous' quarters on the *Invisible
>   Hand*, which was destroyed shortly thereafter in the final moments of
>   the battle.
>   <sub>[Dooku's lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku%27s_lightsaber)</sub>

This demise remains true in both Legends and Canon.

Comment: But why didn't he just keep it?

Comment: Presumably because Anakin was distracted by saving Palpatine and Kenobi. We don't really have any way of knowing.

Comment: Although this is correct, you might want to highlight where and how the wiki gained this information. As a fan-written source, it's often incorrect or at least rather vague on how they know things